# How to take string base 2 as integer?

Tags: python

I want to take this string `'01101011`'  as an `0b01101011` integer in Python.I couldn't find any method to do that.I tried:

```
a=a+"0b"
a=int(a)
```

But is has no use.Can you help me guys?

Comment: Try `a='01101011'`, then `a = int(a, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String to bitstring:**
Convert the string to integer then to binarystring.

```
>>> a_str = '101011'
>>> a_bit_str = bin(int('101011',2))
>>> a_bit_str
'0b101011'
```

**String to Integer:**
If you just want to convert string to integer

```
>>> int(a_str,2)
43
```